# SqliteDatabase Handler - why does first write query take longer than others

Tags: android, database, sqlite, time

I got an app with a database.

It gets only called once by the Application class and the reference then is forwarded to whoever needs it. When it gets initialized I call `db  = this.getWritableDatabase();` and leave it open. While every write operation of a simple Double takes around 6-10 ms, the frist on needs with 30-50 ms up to 8 times as long.

How does that come? Is it the initialization? I thought that calling `getWritableDatabase()` would initialize everything for me? Or is there another reason? Can I read somewhere about it, why and how it behaves?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: To make this more clear: the values get written way after the initialization of the DB handler, so the initilization will be long over.

EDIT 2: now that I digged deeper into the topic I found 2 things:

1. it is said that queries on unindexed tables would be slower. is that always true? doesn't android create an index like sqlite_autoindex_tablename_1. doesn't that solve that?
2. that the `getWritableDatabase()` does not really open anything but that it really gets loaded when the first cursor operation (like `cursor.move()` ) is executed? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase ()
```

Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened and

```
 onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), 
 onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and/or 
 onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) will be called.
```

**Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database.)**

Errors such as bad permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.

Database upgrade may take a long time, you should not call this method from the application main thread, including from ContentProvider.onCreate().
Returns

**a read/write database object valid until close() is called**

```
Throws

 SQLiteException    if the database cannot be opened for writing.
```

I hope this is help you.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer but despite the fact that it really is informative, it does not help me. My database gets created right with the MyApplication object so, as I understand, right at the beginning of the app. This is where it calls the getWritableDatabase. Even if this takes some time, my valueGenerator does wait 5 seconds after his initialization (which is some way along the road AFTER the database has been created) before it starts to write values. So the database is already created and should be ready but still the first write takes up to 60 ms. Any idea how that comes?